# Touchpad permanently disabled after using ambient light sensor button

Tags: 13.04, kubuntu, touchpad, hp, function-keys

I am using an HP/Compaq 8710p and it has an ambient light sensor enable/disable button using Fn+F11. I enabled the ambient light sensor and a notification popped up saying, "Touchpad disabled." After pressing Fn+F11 again, the light sensor disabled, but the touchpad still does not work. How do I go about re-enabling the touchpad, and possibly fixing the ambient light sensor to not use the touchpad? I am using Kubuntu 13.04.

Comment: After a reboot, the touchpad is still shown as SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad under system settings. Also, on this laptop it does not have a button to enable or disable the touchpad.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that now when I press Fn+F11 for ambient light sensor, it does not show the touchpad disable/enable any more.

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem is because <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> button has code `0xB3` which is mapped to button "*disable touchpad*".  The solution is, to remap that code to another button. You can use the program **showkey** to verify key code.

I had same problem with my HP EliteBook 8460p and I created a path for **udev** which fixed it:

- [Step 1](https://code.launchpad.net/~pali/ubuntu/raring/udev/hp-elitebook-8460p/+merge/157420)
- [Step 2](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/commit/?id=72bd03c636b72156e93ea43886b0b54d96446d27)

Maybe you should contact ubuntu/udev developers that your notebook (with DMI info) needs similar udev hook too.